# Double sum over random variables and Wald's equation

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables, expected-value

EDIT: I've added some more reasoning below in the hope that it might prompt an answer from someone.

So I've been using Wald's equation to work with something that looks roughly as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_k$$
where $X_t$ is a random variable which depends on the time period $t$, and $\mathbb{I}_k$ are i.i.d. indicator variables for an event that is independent of $X_t$ (for all $t$). I know that I can write $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_k\right) = \mathbb{E}(X_t)\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_k).$$
My question is, can I do the same thing for a product of these sums, e.g. suppose that $X_t$ and $X_{t-m}$ for $m<t$ are *dependent* random variables. Then if $\mathbb{I}_k$ is independent of $\mathbb{I}_j$ for all $j=1,\dots X_{t-m}$, and $k=1,\dots, X_t$, is it true that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}}\mathbb{I}_j\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_k\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}(X_{t-m}X_t)\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I_j}\mathbb{I_k}).$$
I guess what I'm looking for is a version of Wald's equation for products of sums whose upper limits are dependent random variables. The reason the above equation "makes sense" to me is because there are $X_{t-m}X_t$ products of indicator variables in the expansion of the sum, so in some sense you could write it as a single sum with an upper limit of $X_{t-m}X_t$, but I'm not comfortable enough with the algebra of random variables to be certain that this is allowed.

EDIT: To add a bit more reasoning here, let's first write
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}}\mathbb{I}_j\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_k\right) = \sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}}\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_j\mathbb{I}_k.$$
Now, if the random variables $X_t$ and $X_{t-m}$ were to be realised as $x_t$ and $x_{t-m}$, we would have pairs $x_tx_{t-m}$ total pairs $(j,k)$, and hence $x_tx_{t-m}$ different terms of the form $\mathbb{I}_j\mathbb{I}_k$ in the double sum, **so it seems natural to say that we have $X_tX_{t-m}$ different terms of this form when the $X$'s have not yet been realised.** Now let's enumerate all of these pairs $(j,k)$ as $\{(j_1,k_1), (j_2,k_2),\dots, (j_{X_tX_{t-m}},k_{X_tX_{t-m}}\}$ in no particular order. Then we could write that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}}\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_j\mathbb{I}_k= \sum_{l=1}^{X_tX_{t-m}}\mathbb{I}_{j_l}\mathbb{I}_{k_l},$$
and finally apply Wald's equation directly to this to get that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}}\mathbb{I}_j\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_k\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{l=1}^{X_tX_{t-m}}\mathbb{I}_{j_l}\mathbb{I}_{k_l}\right] = \mathbb{E}(X_{t-m}X_t)\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I_j}\mathbb{I_k}),$$
the desired result. The part in **bold** above is the part that I'm not sure is "allowed". **Can you move from realised random variables to unrealised random variables in this way?**

One consequence of this (for example) would be that I could use the same reasoning to compute
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t}}\mathbb{I}_j\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t}\mathbb{I}_k\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=k}\mathbb{I}_j+\sum_{j\neq k}\mathbb{I}_j\mathbb{I}_k\right] = \mathbb{E}(X_t)\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_j) + \mathbb{E}(X_t^2 - X_t)\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_j\mathbb{I}_k).$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first approach is that $\mathbb{I}_j \mathbb{I}_k$ is not identically distributed over all pairs $(j,k)$, so you cannot use Wald's equation there. Your second approach is correct for that case where $X_t$ is the same as $X_{t-m}$.

In the general case,

\begin{align}
E\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}} I_j \right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t} I_k \right)\right]
&= E\left[E\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{X_{t-m}} I_j \right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{X_t} I_k \right) \middle|\; X_{t-m}, X_t\right]\right]
\\
&= E\left[
E\left[\sum_{j=1}^{\min\{X_{t-m}, X_t\}} I_j\;\middle|\; X_t, X_{t-m}\right]
\right]
+ E\left[E\left[
\sum_{j=1}^{X_t} \sum_{1 \le k \le X_{t-m}; k \ne j} I_j I_k
\;\middle|\; X_t, X_{t-m}\right]\right]
\\
&= E[\min\{X_{t-m}, X_t\}] E[I_1] + (X_t X_{t-m} - \min\{X_t, X_{t-m}\}) E[I_1 I_2].
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this. In the case I'm working with I think $\mathbb{I_j}\mathbb{I_k}$ are actually identically distributed over all pairs $(j,k)$. In particular, $\mathbb{I}_j$ is defined by the conditional distribution
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{I}_j = x \mid p_j = p) = xp + (1-x)(1-p).
$$
where $p_j$ is a uniform [0,1] random variable, and $p_j$ is drawn independently for every $j$. The indicator variables $\mathbb{I_j}$ and $\mathbb{I_k}$ are determined by some $p_j$ and $p_k$ which are identical and independent of each other for every $j$ and $k$. So in that case, am I ok?

Comment: I should also add, in my case $X_t$ is a decreasing sequence of random variables, that is, $X_t \le X_{t-m}$ for all $0<m\le t$. This is because $X_{t+1} = X_t - \sum_{j=1}^{f(X_t)}\mathbb{I_j}$ for some explicit function $f$ of $X_t$ which I won't go into here so as to not get bogged down too much in the details, so in this case the min of the two will always be $X_t$. I should have made these things explicit but I guess I didn't realise what I was assuming until I saw your answer!

Comment: @deej Regarding your first comment: no, the issue is that although $I_j I_k$ has the same distribution as $I_1 I_2$ for any $j \ne k$, the terms of the form $I_j I_j$ have a different distribution. This invalidates the very last step of your first attempt when you apply Wald's inequality.

Comment: @deej Your second comment is much more problematic. My answer is operating under the assumption that the sequence $X_t$ is independent of the $I_j$ (as stated in your first paragraph). If $X_t$ has the form you have given in your comment, where it depends on the $I_j$, then my answer does not hold.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I can clear this up- what I should have written for the indicator variables is $\mathbb{I}_j^t$ and $\mathbb{I}_k^{t-m}$. These are not the same indicator variables, and so $X_t$ is independent of $\mathbb{I}_j^t$, but is not independent of $\mathbb{I}_j^{t-m}$ for $m>0$. Basically with each $t$ we get a new set of independent indicator variables. I realise that was not clear from the original post! That should mean the argument you've given is valid.

Comment: To clarify, the $t$'s are not powers, maybe I should ave written $\mathbb{I}_{j,t}$ instead to indicate the dependency on $t$. I realise this actually changes the question quite a bit - I'l update the post accordingly in an edit at the bottom of the post.